# Drag and drop images within webview in Flask python

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, flask

I am fairly new to python and i am working on Flask. I have to implement a webview where images fetched from certain path are to be rendered and have to provide functionality for user to sort the order of images by drag and drop (basically shuffling images) so that i get the order of images post shuffle which i have to user later.

Any help here would be appreciated. 
Many thanks.

Comment: show what you have done o far

Comment: This looks promising [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294705/jquery-ui-sortable-save-to-database-with-python-flask-sqlite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294705/jquery-ui-sortable-save-to-database-with-python-flask-sqlite)

Comment: Thanks @bren. This really helped